# Как осуществить перенаправление без сообщений браузера?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, javascript

Есть задача перенаправлять при `js`-ошибках

```
function ErrorScript() {
     top.location.href = "error.aspx";
}
window.onerror = ErrorScript;
aa("sdf"); // имитация ошибки
```

Если получать `stack overflow`, то сначала идёт сообщение браузера, а потом уже перенаправление

```
function aa(i) {
   aa(i++);
}
```

Если получать синтаксическую ошибку, то вообще не перенаправляет, а браузер показывает ошибку

```
function aa(i) {
       return return;
}
```

Нужно, чтобы всегда было перенаправление и никаких сообщений браузера (`IE8`, желательно под все, но главное под `IE8`). Помогите пожалуйста. Возможны варианты на `jQuery`.

Comment: обернуть в try catch ?

Comment: Поясните, для каждого скрипта? или для всего можно?

Comment: Расскажите подробнее, что надо сделать! Я уверен, что решение где-то на поверхности, вы, просто лезете вглубь...

Comment: Если есть любая js ошибка, то чтоб она не показывалась юзеру, а перенаправляла на страницу, мол мы обновляем сайт, подождите, сейчас он недоступен. Подключаемых скриптов много, некоторые прописаны в самих .ascx файлах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function err_handler(msg) {
    top.location.href = "error.aspx";
    return true; // именно true
}
window.onerror = err_handler;

aa('ups');
```

Comment: а параметр msg это что? типа чтоб сообщение вместо вывода попадало в функцию?

Comment: не помогает((

Comment: Хм... [Тут примере](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/aawP6/) сделал задержку, чтоб успеть рассмотреть. И вроде, как работает.

Comment: спасибо, просто синтаксические не ловит, а так ок. ещё бы как нибудь строку ошибки узнать бы..

Comment: Ну, вот вам и ответ на то, зачем **msg** ))

Comment: так msg текст ошибки же выдает))
UPD.
Сорри, нашёл инфу про остальные параметры)

Comment: @Sleepless, Значит, я вас не так понял.

    function err_handler(msg, url, lineNumber) {
        alert(msg + ' <> ' + url + ' <> ' + lineNumber);
        return true; // именно true
    }
    window.onerror = err_handler;